# Ratchet doesn't start in AWS EC2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ratchet

I'm trying to start my chat server on ec2, but I have no success, I don't have any idea to solve it, I don't know if the problem is port. On my computer the server starts perfectly but in ec2 doesn't, please help me I really need  to fix it. I already allowed the port 8080 on the ec2, but no success

EC2 Error

[image: 1]

Comment: I'm about days trying to solve it, I'm really sad because of that, can someone help?? please

Comment: What is Ec2? you have a link with more information about that, I thougd Ratchet needs to run on a different port and on most hosting providers you get only port 80 for internet traffic

Comment: Have you considered reaching out to AWS support?

Comment: I took a look at their website, but it seems that to get in touch to talk about it, I must have a plan that I don't have

Comment: Even using port 80 I have no success :/

Comment: I have a line in the js file var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
Is it the problem? Because I don't want to start the server in localhost, but in the dns server, so, should I put my website in new WebSocket("http:/mysite.com"); ?

Comment: I did it, but I still have the same problem. Oh, that's so bad, I don't know what to do anymore